# How to know count or last of messages in MediaGroup telegram

Tags: telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

I want to attach a button for a media group

1. To do this, I intercept the message and see if there is the same mediaGroup_id, then I save the file_id to the database
2. After all messages from this media group have been received, I send them to a group in a separate channel (here is the problem) -> *how can I determine that this is the last message from the media group, I had a stupid idea to create a job with a delay of several seconds, enough time to receive the entire media group, and then send the entire media group in this job, however, I am worried about the reliability of this method, and for sure it will be buggy if one day I have to use asynchronous*
3. Then, in the main channel, I send a message containing a link to the media group and a button, as I wanted

Is there some way to do this more elegantly?

Answer (score 1):

That actually sounds rather reasonable and in fact I know a bot that does [something very similar](https://github.com/Poolitzer/channelforwarder/blob/589104b8a808199ba46d620736bd8bea1dc187d9/main.py#L35-L46). The idea why this works, is that TG apparently first uploads all the media files and then sends all messages at once rather then looping over "upload, then send".